# permission storage lock screen

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I'm trying to run my app for all devices, but I have a problem with a storage permit in some phones. my app changes the background both in the home and in the block screen through the following code

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            Uri sendUri =  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/0prova/"+intclick+".jpg");
            myintent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myintent, "Set As.."));
```

and this window opens
when i click on the icon lock screen (schermata di blocco) nothing happens.

[image]

but if I follow these steps and allow permission everything works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the questions are: can i change it automatically with the code?or go to the page and enabled by the user?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the console print anything when the user clicks for the first time on "Schermata blocco" ?

Comment: nothing happens if the user do not get that permission